# Installtion Nightmare on iMac

Tags: installation, mac

Well I have searched far and wide for some solutions but I decided to take all the problems I have had into one.

First I have a 27" Apple iMac (Late 2009 Release) running a intel i7, 4GB of RAM, and ATI Radeon HD 4850 card with the standard airport extreme 2 which is running MAc OS X Lion (10.7.4) I checked the hardware support and Ubuntu seems to be ok after some tweaking.

So here is what I did in the exact order based on some lengthy research.

First I downloaded rEFIt (version .14) and installed it. I did a quick halt and reboot and it work.

Next I wasn't sure whether to trust ubuntu to parition my main drive or handle it myself. So I decided to go for the self partitioning. Did you know that partitioning on Lion is not like partitioning on Leopard?

I ended up reparing the disk and rebooting into recovery mode and making the partitions there. I have a 1TB hard and I slipt it up as so (Approx.) MacOS = 575 Exfat(I called it Data) 350 and 75Gb Free Space.

Next I downloaded the 64 bit version of the newest ubuntu release Ubuntu 12.04.iso and burnt it to disk using the slowest write speed.

Next I inserted the disk and restarted the and held "C" it booted to from the CD and I was at the first menu in the Ubuntu phase. I first selected the Language then Install Ubuntu. Immediatly the screen went black but the disc was still reading. I immediatly realized this was Either a GUI issue or a Display issue. So I did some research and found out about the 'nomodeset' I did that and the install ran well. At least I thought. I restarted the Mac and waited for the EFI Boot menu or Grub menu. Nothing. So I shutdown and powered up again and this time held 'Alt' the menu came up and I selected the Windows Disk and then it went to the grub menu and I then had the choice again. I chose Ubuntu obviously. Purple screen popped up thenn!    Command Line. I figured the disk failed and so I connected to my wifi and then proceed to update and then install the ubuntu desktop. I tried running the startX command but got nothing ESC and f6 failed me and so I shutdown. When i rebooted the mac goes straight to OS X. Its quit bothersome and I am surprise that this is this difficult. I suspect the Recovery Drive Lion create is to blame.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/ and download the special mac version of the release. I just installed on a Macbook Pro 17" Late 2009 and it worked out of the box!

Also i suggest using rEFInd as rEFit is no longer in development. 
If you don not want to struggle with the EFI booting just add the
   `hdbios`
option in your refind.conf file's 
   `scanfor`
line.

Answer (score -1):

To install on Mac by CD , then Download the iso Version then Burn the iso file into the CD.
After that restart your computer and boot it from the cd

Comment: The OP has done exactly that.

Comment: I did that. Thats not the problem the problem is Ubuntu Install screen (i.e. Where you chose to Install or try) comes up but as soon as I select something it goes black. I know its the fact that it switches to the display port but how can I fix this?

Answer (score -2):

You're likely going to want to download the latest 13.04 version, I have had a lot of issues with 12.x series and proprietary video cards. So far 13.04 is working much better in this regard.

Comment: I have 12.x running on MacBook, iMac and MacMini with no issues, so my experience is different to yours. Just thought I'd add that so user doesn't get a false impression.